# How can I debug segmentation faults in the PHP CLI?

Tags: ubuntu, php-5.3, php

I have written some code that I run remotely on a server via the php-cli and a particular method within this code (I'm unsure *which method* at the moment) is causing a `segmentation fault`.

Apart from adding `exit` and `echo` calls down through my methods and manually pinpointing the bad bits -  **is there a way to catch the segmentation fault as it happens** and find out what piece of the puzzle is crashing? Standard PHP errors are displayed through the error shutdown handlers, I'm unsure where to start with this segmentation fault.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. With the GNU Debugger: [how-to-debug-a-segmentation-fault-caused-by-php](http://www.trafexisblogging.com/2009/12/how-to-debug-a-segmentation-fault-caused-by-php/)

Or by setting the flag `DBIG_SECURITY_HOLE` when you compile php: [Fixing Apache Segmentation Faults Caused by PHP](http://www.omh.cc/blog/2008/mar/6/fixing-apache-segmentation-faults-caused-php/)

Take a look at [bugs.php.net](https://bugs.php.net/) maybe there is a related known bug in the PHP source.

Comment: Thanks for the links @Besnik. The particular PHP scripts I'm running have nothing to do with Apache, but it's a reasonable start at catching the seg faults.

Comment: Both links are about Apache?